# Unable to maximize Safari browser on MAC with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, macos, selenium, safari, webdriver

We are using Selenium with Java to automate our Web application. We have working code to run automated test scripts on Windows operating system for the three browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox - Latest version).

We have got the requirement to run automated test scripts on MAC operating system - Safari browser.

**Environment Details:**

**MAC OS version** : macOS Sierra version 10.12.5

**Safari browser version** : 10.1.1(12603.2.4)

**Selenium standalone server version** : 3.4.0

**Java version** : 1.8.0_112

Connected MAC VM with VNC viewer (Sys admin team provided MAC VM for our testing).

While executing test scripts on MAC, below code is not maximizing Safari browser, which is working fine for other browsers(IE, Chrome and Firefox) on Windows. Due to this we are unable to locate some of the controls on application.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

We are not getting any exception, code is executing but not performing any action.

Please help to overcome Safari browser maximize issue on MAC.

Really I thought my issue got resolved with this solution, tried code to maximize Safari browser, but getting exception.

Code:

```
 SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.setUseCleanSession(true);
driver = new SafariDriver(options);
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String screenWidth = jse.executeScript("return screen.availWidth").toString();
String screenHeight = jse.executeScript("return screen.availHeight").toString();
int intScreenWidth = Integer.parseInt(screenWidth);
int intScreenHeight = Integer.parseInt(screenHeight);
org.openqa.selenium.Dimension d = new org.openqa.selenium.Dimension(intScreenWidth, intScreenHeight);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

Exception:

> Aug 07, 2017 3:11:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: A request to use a window
>   could not be satisfied because the window could not be found.
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 27 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '3.4.0', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800' System
>   info: host: 'Mac.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4c6:11dc:3f91:11f8%en0',
>   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, databaseEnabled=true,
>   handlesAlerts=true, version=12603.3.8, cleanSession=true,
>   platform=MAC, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=false,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   platformName=macOS, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   BA265536-18D3-490E-B6DB-40D8BBF25937
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.setSize(RemoteWebDriver.java:860)
>       at Sample.Safari.main(Safari.java:20)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safari browser maximize issue got resolved after upgrading Safari version to 11.0(12604.1.35)

And the working code is

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Hi, I wrote the fix. I can confirm that Safari 11 and later should not have the problem described in the question.

Answer (score -1):

We have observe bug with new driver libraries. You can use slightly old jars which is able to handle new browsers versions.

You can also use other option for maximize the browser window.

Example :-

Add below option and pass it to driver :-

```
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

The full code will look like below :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

OR

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
int Width = (int) toolkit.getScreenSize().getWidth();
int Height = (int)toolkit.getScreenSize().getHeight();
//For Dimension class, Import following library "org.openqa.selenium.Dimension"  
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(Width,Height));
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

OR

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.resizeTo(1024, 768);");
```

Try this on safari :-

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String screenWidth = jse.executeScript("return screen.availWidth").toString();
String screenHeight = jse.executeScript("return screen.availHeight").toString();
int intScreenWidth = Integer.parseInt(screenWidth);
int intScreenHeight = Integer.parseInt(screenHeight);
Dimension d = new Dimension(intScreenWidth, intScreenHeight);
driver.manage.window.setSize(d);
```

Below article will have these example in details :-

http://www.abodeqa.com/2015/01/20/maximize-window-using-selenium-webdriver-and-by-using-abstract-window-toolkit/

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. We have issue with Safari browser.

Comment: I have tried to run code to maximize Safari, but getting exception. I thought with the provided solution my issue got resolved, but no luck for us.

Comment: have you tried ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.resizeTo(1024, 768);");

Comment: JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.resizeTo(1360, 768)");  This code also not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151262/discussion-between-aparna-and-shubham-jain).